# Creating a column with sum of multiple columns grouped by name in panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset and I need to get the sum from two other columns and group them by name.

DF

```
 a       b        c
Joe      1        0
Joe      1        0
Joe      0        1
Adam     1        0
Adam     0        1
Adam     0        0
```

Desired Output:

```
  a        b      c       d
 Joe       1      0       1
 Joe       1      0       2
 Joe       0      1       3
 Adam      1      0       1
 Adam      0      1       2
 Adam      0      0       2
```

I have tried `df['d'] = df.groupby('a')['b','c'].sum()`

When I do this I get NaN as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a cumulative sum grouped on that column.
Something like this should work

```py
df['sum'] = df['b'] + df['c']
df['d'] = df.groupby('a')['sum'].cumsum()
```

which gives

```
a       b    c  sum d
0   Joe 1   0   1   1
1   Joe 1   0   1   2
2   Joe 0   1   1   3
3   Adam 1  0   1   1
4   Adam 0  1   1   2
5   Adam 0  0   0   2
```

Comment: Without intermediate: `df['d'] = df[['b', 'c']].sum(axis=1).groupby(df['a']).cumsum()`